# how to choose proxy server

Tags: reverse-proxy, hardware

I'm trying to determine which proxy server software I should use.

The `concurrent user base` is about 1000 user. I'm guessing the `Per Second  Http request`is around 500.

I've decided to use some hosting as a proxy server but I don't know how to choose a better proxy server : either apache or weblogic?

Which one is better? How should I be determining the hardware requirements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My 2 cents would be to recommend to you either Varnish(first choice), PerlBal or Nginx. If you need to set up a dedicated cache/load balancing server, Apache is not highly recommended. Varnish is according to our own internal assessment the best.

However I do not think your problem can be solely solved with Caching and Load Balancing. You may need to visit your web architecture, and start optimizing from there, if your application actually has 500 requests a second. Of course answering those questions require lot more input.
 Varnish to my best of knowledge is a multi-threaded app, and hence should scale on multi-core multi processor platforms. So you can throw more CPU and scale up performance.

Comment: Can you comment as to why Varnish was the best?  Curious to know how you came to that conclusion.

Comment: @gravyface Varnish was written from ground up as a reverse proxy to high traffic systems, and their [Architecture Notes](http://www.varnish-cache.org/trac/wiki/ArchitectNotes) are pretty impressive when showing why it is faster and more powerful. Also, there are the use cases for Varnish that are pretty impressive.

Comment: @gravyfaceWe had run a test when we had set up a rack for a customer around 8 months back. Honestly we concluded Apache may not be the best purely based on forum opinions, and benchmarked Perlbal, Nginx and Varnish using AB. Varnish scaled the best on a Quad Core Xeon processor E3430.It's also important to note that we tried Citrix NetScaler and a box from F5 Networks, which very easily out performed the rest. But these were commercial offerings, and way out of the budget of our customer. If you have the bucks, then try one of those commercial boxes.

Comment: Heard good things about HAProxy as it's purely a proxy and nothing more.

Comment: Lets mention pound too then!

Comment: i will try nginx,and have a pressure testing.thank you ramdaz.